# Strange characters added to URL in MVC application (X(1)S(xxxxxxxx), response says Object Moved,why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, iis

I have an MVC app and when I first open it up (in a new browser, ie new session) I am getting some strange characters added to my url after the site name part. It always starts with (X(1)S( and the characters change each time.

(X(1)S(y2bk1ahqgpv42uwh0mcpsdxw))

Does anyone have any ideas what is causing this? Is this some cookie setting in IIS or web.config?

It's causing some problems, one of which is the modelstate is invalid due to an error with no error messages.

Deploying to IIS.

Get the following response in Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /mysite/(X(1)S(hvuk0jbaokfmxtlvm54d4cvc))/

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/mysite/(X(1)S(hvuk0jbaokfmxtlvm54d4cvc))
```

Not sure what other info I can give that could be relevant, I'm hoping someone has seen these characters before and know what they're about.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was bothering me all day then as soon as I put it on SO I find the reason.

The original URL I was requesting had the following querystring parameter.

```
&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
```

Remove this and although it gets appended automatically the other characters don't and everything works.

The problem was we had copied the URL in the past with this parameter as it had been automatically added. However if you request a url with this parameter in it, you get the above issue.

I think this is the solution, maybe others know some more information.